# Input effect on keyboard tab -> focus, but NOT on click

Tags: css, user-interface, input, focus

When a user 'tabs over' to an input, I want the focus effect to be normally displayed, but on click, I don't want it to be visible.

User **hits tab**, now focussed on toggle button, I would like the toggle button to have slight glowing outline, which I'm currently able to do.

Now,

User **clicks** on the toggle button or it's associated label, toggle changes as usual, 
**BUT**, I want the glow to never appear in the first place, or to disappear as quickly as possible.

I know about `.blur()`, and right now I'm having to use a `setTimeout` for a lazy fix, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to accomplish this, or if there's possibly a **CSS only solution**

Answer (score 9):

I think a lot of front-end developers struggle to find a balance between aesthetics and the best-practices for accessibility. This seems like a great compromise.

Here's how I do it. The idea is to toggle outlining on when the user uses the tab key and turn it back off when they click.

### JS

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    $('body').addClass('show-focus-outlines');
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  $('body').removeClass('show-focus-outlines');
});
```

### Styles

```
body:not(.show-focus-outlines) button:focus, 
body:not(.show-focus-outlines) [tabindex]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: You may also want to select for `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `a` tags in your styles. jQuery UI does a good job of describing some other elements that are tabbable here. https://api.jqueryui.com/tabbable-selector/

Comment: what is this <style> syntax listed above? with nested styles?

Comment: @Ash Sorry, that's a SASS feature. I'll rewrite.

Comment: this is very good ! it can be simpler, just add the class (.hide-focus) so you can write `.hide-focus :focus { outline: none }`

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently doing something similar for my company. Unfortunately you must use JavaScript since CSS doesn't support this use case.

Here's what I've done.

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

var onMouseDown = function (evt) {
  evt.target.dataset.pressed = 'true';
};

var onMouseUp = function (evt) {
  evt.target.dataset.pressed = 'false';
};

var onFocus = function (evt) {
  var element = evt.target;
  if (element.dataset.pressed !== 'true') {
    element.classList.add('focus');
  }
};

var onBlur = function (evt) {
  evt.target.classList.remove('focus');
};

for(var i = 0, l = btns.length; i < l; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
  btns[i].addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp); 
  btns[i].addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
  btns[i].addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { background-color: white; }

button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #646e7c;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

button:focus { outline: none; }

button:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(1px);
  transform: translateY(1px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button.focus {
  font-weight: bold;
}

button.primary { background-color: #2093d0; }

button.success { background-color: #71a842; }

button.danger { background-color: #ef4448; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button>Default</button>
  <button class="primary">Primary</button>
  <button class="success">Success</button>
  <button class="danger">Danger</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically instead of relying on browser's native focus I add/remove a `focus` class on my button depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [what-input.js](https://github.com/ten1seven/track-focus)  plugin you can apply styles specifically for keyboard users. You can use the following code to highlight a button that  has been tabbed to. I've found what-input to be a reliable plugin (comes bundled with Zurb Foundation) and is currently regularly maintained.

```
// scss
body[data-whatinput="keyboard"] {
  button {
    &:focus {
      // other highlight code here
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
/* vanilla css */
body[data-whatinput="keyboard"] button:focus {
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```