# Is it possible to style just focus on tab at checkboxes?

Tags: html, css

I wonder if it is possible to style just focus on tab (using ↹ to navigate through the page)but not if the user click on the item.

Just like the default behaviour of checkboxes. It gets a blue outline (looks like box-shadow) if I use tab.

Like I want a new red box-shadow/outline on focus by tab but not if the user clicks on the checkbox.

```html
<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Do you mean “tap”?

Comment: @AjAX. tab not tap

Comment: @Paili see my answer

Comment: Why on tab and not on click?

Comment: I want other styles at focus on click ;) @TakitIsy

Comment: This topic may interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705055/input-effect-on-keyboard-tab-focus-but-not-on-click/32869452#32869452 Maybe that's even some kind of duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can do it by Jquery**

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    $('#checkBox').addClass('outline');
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  $('#checkBox').removeClass('outline');
});
```

```css
.outline{
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
```

**OR**
this plugin:https://github.com/ten1seven/track-focus 
**in css:**

```
body[data-whatinput="keyboard"] #checkBox:focus {
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px red;
}
```

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I was looking for :) But I hoped I could do it with pure CSS :D @לבני מלכה

Answer (score 0):

You could style all possible states of the checkbox:

```css
   input:focus {
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(255,0,0,.5);
    }
    input:checked {
      box-shadow: none;  
      /* HIDE OUTLINE - ACCESSIBILITY BAD PRACTICE */
      outline: none;
    }
```

```html
    <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Jeah, that is possible but I want no red-border if I click on it. Only if I tab through and focus it. @Ander

Comment: Ok, but if you click on it the input become checked, so the checked selector is trigger

Comment: No, look at the default behaviour of a checkbox. It gets a blue shadow only if I tab through but not if I click. No matter if checked or unchecked the blue border does not appear when I click on it focus it this way. Only if I focus it on tab. It also get no blue box-shadow if I hover just when I tab through.  @לבנימלכה

Comment: No, look at the default behaviour of a checkbox. It gets a blue shadow only if I tab through but not if I click. No matter if checked or unchecked the blue border does not appear when I click on it focus it this way. Only if I focus it on tab.It also get no blue box-shadow if I hover just when I tab through.  @Ander

Comment: I don't understand what you really want, maybe are you talking about the outline property? I've changed my answer to check if this is it.

Comment: Sorry really hard to explain :D Almost correct. But I don't want the outline to disappear. I want a red outline and also want to declare on my own which blur the outline has @Ander

Comment: Hum, AFAIK, you can't style the outline of an input element besides the basics: none, dotted, solid, ... (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-style), the alternative would be to always hide the outline and style the rest of the states: focus, checked

Answer (score 0):

Focus will be when you're holding the mouse down on it. If you don't want it when clicked you can use hover instead.

```css
   input:hover {
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(255,0,0,.5);  
    }
    input:checked {
      box-shadow: none;  
    }
```

```html
    <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
```

You can also create your own styling by styling the label. check this out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: Thank you for the Link! But look at the default behaviour of a checkbox. It gets a blue shadow only if I tab through but not if I click. No matter if checked or unchecked the blue border does not appear when I click on it focus it this way. Only if I focus it on tab. It also get no blue box-shadow if I hover just when I tab through. @Naomi

Comment: Not really sure what you want it to do?

Comment: me too i dont undrestand... do you use any library(like bootstrap)

Comment: I want a red outline on tab. But this should be not visible if I click on it  Sorry, its really hard to explain this :D @Naomi

Comment: border or shaddow?

Comment: It should look like box-shadow. @לבנימלכה

Comment: allways shadow and on click not shadow??

Comment: No shadow only if you use ↹ to navigate through the page @לבנימלכה

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution from the link I provided you in a comment,
([Input effect on keyboard tab -> focus, but NOT on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705055/input-effect-on-keyboard-tab-focus-but-not-on-click/32869452#32869452))

Here is what I'll do:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    body.classList.add('show-focus-outlines');
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  body.classList.remove('show-focus-outlines');
});
```

```css
body.show-focus-outlines input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px red;
}

body:not(.show-focus-outlines) input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</body>
```

Note that I used Javascript only (in the link, that was jQuery),
and tried to render something nice with the CSS.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

very simple.
you can use `:focus` for styling elements
if you want different style for Clicked on object use `:active` to style it.

here is an example for `<a>` tag.

```css
.click,.focus{
color : red;
text-decoration: none;
}
.click:focus{
outline: none;
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #fff;
}
.click:active{
color: green;
background-color: #fda;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
}

.focus:focus{
color: green;
background-color: #fda;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
.focus:active{
outline: none;
color: red !important;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<a class="click" href="#">Click Me</a><br>
<a class="focus" href="#">Focus me[use Tab]</a>
```